# sorting every cell with data in excel using VBA

Tags: excel

I recorded a macro for sorting this sheet. how do I replace the hardcoded ranges so that this script works with any number of rows?

```
Worksheets(1).sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
Worksheets(1).sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("A2:A130008"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending _
    , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
Worksheets(1).sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("B2:B130008"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending _
    , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
Worksheets(1).sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("C2:C130008"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending _
    , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
Worksheets(1).sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("D2:D130008"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending _
    , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
Worksheets(1).sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("E2:E130008"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending _
    , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
Worksheets(1).sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("P2:P130008"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
    xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
Worksheets(1).sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("Q2:Q130008"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
    xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With Worksheets(1).sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:R130008")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do the job. Please try it.

```
Sub StackOverflow()

    Dim Rng         As Range            ' range to sort
    
    With Worksheets(1)
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) _
                  .Resize(, .Columns("R").Column)
        ' .Columns("R").Column = 18 and may be replaced with this number
        
        With .Sort.SortFields
            .Clear
            ' specify the columns to sort on in sequence of priority
            .Add2 Key:=Rng.Cells(1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                  Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add2 Key:=Rng.Cells(2), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                  Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add2 Key:=Rng.Cells(3), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                  Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add2 Key:=Rng.Cells(4), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                  Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add2 Key:=Rng.Cells(5), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                  Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add2 Key:=Rng.Cells(16), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                  Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add2 Key:=Rng.Cells(17), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                  Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        With .Sort
            .SetRange Rng
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that in `.Sort.SetRange` the entire range must be specified whereas for setting each of the Keys just one cell is required to identify a column. Since the cells in a range are numbered 1 and up first across and then down the first 18 cell numbers in the range coincide with the column numbers in the underling sheet range. So `Key:=Rng.Cells(1)` happens to be `Worksheets(1).Cells(2, "A")` based on how `Rng` was specified. I chose the shorter syntax but the effect is that the entire range will first be sorted on column A before other keys are applied.